# undefined table PG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im getting a error when trying to add provider to my p_list. It's saying  undefined table but doesn't really clarify?

Heres my error 'PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "p_lists" does not exist LINE 8: WHERE a.attrelid = '"p_lists"'::regclass ^ : SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod, c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation WHERE a.attrelid = '"p_lists"'::regclass AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped ORDER BY a.attnum'

```
class patient_controller < ApplicationController
def add_provider
        @patient = current_user.current_role.roleable
        @provider = Provider.find(params[:provider_id])
        @plist = PList.where(
            :membershipable_type => 'Patient',
            :membershipable_id => params[:membershipable_id],
            :provider_id => params[:provider_id]).first_or_create do |plist|
                plist.membershipable_type = 'Patient'
                plist.membershipable_id = params[:membershipable_id]
                plist.provider_id = params[:provider_id]
            end
         @mplist.soft_delete = false
     if @plist.save
         flash[:success] = "You are now a member of " + @site.name + "."
           redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
     else
         flash[:error] = @plist.errors.full_messages.to_sentence

     end
    end

end
```

Here is my table for p_list

```
create_table "p_list", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "membershipable_type"
    t.bigint "membershipable_id"
    t.integer "patient_id"
    t.boolean "soft_delete", default: false
    t.integer "provider_id"
    t.index ["membershipable_type", "membershipable_id"], name: "index_p_list_on_membershipable_type_and_membershipable_id"
  end
```

Here is my model for p_list

```
class PList < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :membershipable, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :provider
end
```

Lastely here is my provider model

```
class Provider < ApplicationRecord
has_many :p_list
end
```

Comment: Sounds like you made a `p_list` table, but Rails expects a table named `p_lists`.

Comment: ActiveRecord assumes that table names are plural. Either create `p_lists` other than `p_list` or use `self.table_name = 'p_list'` in your `PList` model to force it to use a non-standard table name.